# Clustered cron with one server only overlap allowed

Tags: linux, centos, haproxy, glusterfs, pid

I've setuped load balancers: `lb1` (active) and `lb2` (passive), Glustered web servers: `web1` (active), `web2` (backup), and some clustered database. Both web servers and databases are `A` pointed to the VIP of the load balancers.

Both of web servers have their copy of cron jobs. Assuming the following tasks:

```
* * * * * echo $(hostname) >> crontab.txt
0 0 1 * * ~/bin/another/task 2>&1
```

With some random lock algorithm:

```
lock_dir=~/.cronlock
pid_file=~/.cronlock/pid

if ( mkdir ${lock_dir} ) 2> /dev/null; then
    echo $$ > $pid_file
    trap 'rm -rf "$lock_dir"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

    # Crons

    rm -rf "$lock_dir"
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
fi
```

Is safe to have something like

```
* * * * * ./lock_algorithm -f LOCK_FILE1 -c "echo $(hostname) >> crontab.txt"
0 0 1 * * ./lock_algorithm -f LOCK_FILE2 -c "~/bin/another/task 2>&1"
```

Where I send a "per-cron-command" unique lock file name and a command to be executed?

By "safe" I mean `web1` OR `web2` will run, not both.

And if I need cron overlap (eg: each minute I perform a long task limited to the current minute)? How to get `web1`'s cron executing again, assuming that `web1` is the active "cron runner"?

Comment: Also see [Running crons on a scaled mirrored servers (cron logic needed)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242693/100397)

Comment: Across two (or more) hosts a PID isn't unique. Will `lock_algorithm` know that the PID refers to a process on the other host? How will it know when the lock is stale?

Comment: @roaima I alread have seen this question. The main issue is the need of manual intervention in case of main web server outage.

Comment: What defines "main" web server in this context? More usefully here, can you use that criterion to determine on which host the `cron` jobs can run?

Comment: @roaima I don't think so. Webservers are picked by load balancer in a active/passive aproach, so, the active server does not know that it is the active one. HAProxy can send additional headers to served web pages, but not to system/cron.

Comment: I could ping each server and verify which one is down, but don't think that this is a good solution. Manual intervention will be required time to time, plus the additional delay in script execution.

Comment: I'm familiar with load balancers. You mentioned "main" server as in active/passive rather than active/active you also seemed to imply a manual switchover. What do you use for your load balancer?

Comment: Why aren't you using posix-locks in gluster and `flock` to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the following is possible for you, but here is an idea of mine:

- Not sure which cluster stack / software you're using, but you could introduce [pacemaker and corosync](http://clusterlabs.org/) on `web1` and `web2`, and use ocf ressource agents for this. To give you an idea, what this is about:

  ```
  primitive p_postfix ocf:heartbeat:postfix \
    params config_dir="/etc/postfix" \
    op monitor interval="10"
  primitive p_symlink ocf:heartbeat:symlink \
    params target="/srv/postfix/cron" \
      link="/etc/cron.d/postfix" \
      backup_suffix=".disabled" \
    op monitor interval="10"
  primitive p_cron lsb:cron \
    op monitor interval=10
  order o_symlink_before_cron inf: p_symlink p_cron
  colocation c_cron_on_symlink inf: p_cron p_symlink
  colocation c_symlink_on_postfix inf: p_symlink p_postfix
  ```
- What this will do is the following:

  - Check whether a file named `postfix` already exists in `/etc/cron.d`.
  - If it does, rename it to `postfix.disabled` (remember, `cron` ignores job definitions with dots in the filename).
  - (Re-)Create the `postfix` job definition as a symlink to `/srv/postfix/cron`.
  - Restart `cron` when it's done.
- This example is out of a active / passive cluster running `postfix`. `Cron` get's only executed on the active `postfix` node.
- You could alter this to remove `postfix` and instead include your webserver.

---

**Edit:** If the above is "too much" for you, here is another idea: You could set up `HAProxy` stats, get this website in your script, parse it and act accordingly depending on the hostname and the status emitted by `HAProxy`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to create a semaphore that works across servers.  While [someone has tried to build that](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/08/wcf-cross-machine-semaphore-with-wcf/) I don't see it being production-ready.  Rather than pushing the technological envelope it might be good to refactor your problem into something that fits available technology.

Does your website have a database?  You could use that for coordination.

If not, how about using a distributed queueing system like kafka or 0mq?